What 5G m.2 cards will be compatible with a m.2 HAT+ adapter board for the Raspberry PI 5?
The following HAT+ is available on Waveshare:
https://www.waveshare.com/pcie-to-4g-5g-m.2-usb3.2-hat-plus.htm
Now on Waveshare they have listed a series of compatible 5G modules:

RM502Q-AE
RM520N-GL
RM530N-GL
SIM8262E-M2
SIM8262A-M2
SIM7600G-H-M.2


These modules support either R15, 316 5G standard.
Does this mean these are pretty much our only options or could other 5G modules work as well?
Is there some sort of standard these adhere to (The adapter board connects to the PCIe slot of the Raspberry PI).
I have seen some other M.2 5G modules that are marketed for laptops, as long as they have the right M.2 size are they good to go?
What other factors contribute to whether a module could work with an adapter board?

Welcome.  You might try using the "SUPPORT" link on the waveshare page...

The Waveshare HAT+ connects to the Raspberry Pi via USB 3.2. This means the M.2 module must support USB for communication.
If the module is USB-compatible, it is more likely to work with the adapter.
